# How to assign an interface to a const

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am feely new to Typescript, in my `const issuesInitialState`, I am trying to assign the interface `IssuesInitialState` but I am getting the following errors.

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Issue': closeDate, description, issueId, lastEditDate, and 6 more.ts(2740)

The expected type comes from property `issue` which is declared here on type `IssuesInitialState`

```
export interface Issue {
  closeDate: string | null;
  description: string;
  issueId: number;
  lastEditDate: string | null;
  priorityId: string;
  projectId: number;
  reportDate: string;
  statusId: string;
  title: string;
  userId: number;
}

interface IssuesInitialState{
  issues:Issue[];
  issue:Issue; 
  issuesByProject:Issue[];
  updateIssue:Issue;
}

export const issuesInitialState:IssuesInitialState = {
  issues: [],
  issue:{},
  issuesByProject: [],
  updateIssue: {},
};
```

So that I can type cast state to `IssuesInitialState`.

```
export const issuesReducer = (
  state = issuesInitialState,
  action: { type: string; payload: Issue }
) :{}=> {
  switch (action.type) {
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Issue` has properties, so in your const, it can't be declared as `{}`. If a variable has a type which is an object with properties you have to declare these properties when you declare the variable.

Hope it's clear enough. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, if I want my issue to have typeof Issue, how would I declare it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe if it's defined as a class.